# Xamarin Forms Shell - load each tab all at once - eager load instead of lazy load

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms, I have used TabbedPage in the past to make tabs, and every tab will be loaded at once, so when you transition to one tab to another, it's already loaded.

Now in a new app, I'm trying out the new Shell in Xamarin 4.0. Two of my tabs have a web browser in it, but it doesn't start trying to load the page until after you have clicked into the tab. Is it possible to have all the tabs in a shell load at once?

Comment: I test it in Xamarin forms v4.0.0.8055-pre1, that is normal. But webview will 
 load slowly in first Tab.What is your version of xamarin forms? Do you used CSS style in your code, if so, it will make this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer to the actual question I asked, however, please see the disclaimer at the bottom.

Xamrin Forms 4.0 preview, to eager load pages use this code:

```
<ShellSection  x:Name="SpotlightShellSection"  Title="Spotlight" Icon="tab_feed.png">
            <ShellContent Title="Stats" >
                <local:StatsPage/>
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Upcoming" >
                <local:UpcomingPage/>
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="ByMonth" >
                <local:ByMonthPage/>
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Stats2" >
                <local:StatsPage/>
            </ShellContent>
        </ShellSection>
```

To Lazy load, use code like this:

```
    <ShellSection  x:Name="SpotlightShellSection"  Title="Spotlight" Icon="tab_feed.png">
<ShellContent Title="Stats" Content="" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Spotlight.StatsPage}" />
<ShellContent Title="Upcoming" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Spotlight.UpcomingPage}"  />
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Spotlight.ByMonthPage}" />
</ShellSection>
```

Warning, which is my problem, the content of WebViews will not necessarily stay loaded in android only.In iOS the webviews keep their content as expected.